# A mixture Gaussian stochastic process and its properties

Tags: stochastic-processes, statistical-inference, probability-limit-theorems

I have come across a stochastic process on which I have two questions.

Let $W(r)$ and $B(r)$ denote two independent Wiener processes, $r \in [0,1]$, and let $-\infty<x<\infty$.

Define the process $P(x)$, such that

- $P(0)=0$;
- $P(x)=\int_0^1W^2(r)dB(xr)$ for each $x$
- $\operatorname{Cov}(P(x),P(y))=(\min\{x,y\})^{1/2}\int_0^1W^2(r)dB(r)$
- $P(x)$ and $P(x+\delta)-P(x)$ are independent conditional on the sigma-field associated with $W(r)$.

My first question is: has this process been studied already, and does it have continuous sample paths? It is a mixture Gaussian process, so far as I can understand, which is why I have studied the four points above only.

The process $P(x)$ is part of the following functional, which I am studying in the context of an M-estimator - in essence, it characterises the limit of the loss function whose minimum is the estimator I am studying:

$-|x|\int^1_0W^2(r)dr+P(x)$

defined, as mentioned above, over $-\infty<x<\infty$.

My second question is: does the functional above have a unique maximum? I am trying to use the arg-max continuous mapping theorem, hence my question.

Comment: The only randomness comes from $W$ and $B$, for a fixed $\omega$, the integral part $\int_{0}^{1}W^{2}(r,\omega)dB(r,\omega)$ is fixed, then the path is just $K x^{1/2}$ for some $K$, hence is continuous, am I correct?

Comment: this is what I am not sure, I have edited my second bullet point to make the nature of the process clearer